# Offset Expressions Dynamic QGIS - Unique non-repeating Numbers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, offset

I am trying to create a layer style that shows line features that share the same geometry, an exploded view for line Features.

What I have done so far via the Offset expressions in QGIS 3.6

```
("Length"  -  "Length"  + rand(0,count('Cable_13260270_443e_46e6_9da1_39282a8c86d7',  intersects( $geometry ,@map_extent))))
```

This is the view with 'Single Line' with multiple Features sharing the same geometry:
[image: Single Line View]

This is after style with Offset and expressions:

[image: Exploded View]

I had to add the "Length"-"Length" to force it to run the Expression for each Feature, if not I ended up with just 1 random number. Perhaps there is a better way?

The issue I am facing is that some of the random numbers repeat, which then hides the line Feature as they then share the exact Offset. I don't mind the changing views when the map changes, as it should based on how many lines are within the map extent. So in a 'busy' area there would be more Offsets and with only 1 line there would be None or just 1 Offset.

How can I make the Offset Expression pull from a list, such as 1,2,3... Array or string or how can the random number be set to non repeating?